# Android animation to shrink and fade out a View at the same time

Tags: android, android-animation

I can do the fade out. But not the shrink. I want it to look like it's going into the distance far, far away.

I want an animation similar to the one used in [www.screamintothevoid.com](http://www.screamintothevoid.com)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That should work like you want it.

animation.xml in /res/anim

```
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:fromXScale="1"
            android:toXScale="0"
            android:fromYScale="1"
            android:toYScale="0"
            android:duration="5000"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%" >
        </scale>

        <alpha
            android:fromAlpha="1"
            android:toAlpha="0"
            android:duration="5000" >
        </alpha>
    </set>
```

to call this animation:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.animation);
textView.startAnimation(animation);
```

Answer (score 5):

To shrink a view change its scale values, for example:

```
TextView textToShrink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_to_shrink);
textToShrink.animate().scaleX(0.3f).scaleY(0.3f).setDuration(600).start();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fade out and shrink a view in one line using androidx libraryy helper class ViewCompat

```
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat;
import android.view.animation.AccelerateInterpolator;

ViewCompat.animate(myView).alpha(0f).scaleX(0.5f).scaleY(0.5f).setDuration(600).setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
```